# How do I call/start an NDK android application from within an SDK application?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have this application in python which I need to start from the user interface which I have done in java.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is an NDK application? What is an SDK application? There is only Android application which can have part or all of it built by using the NDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it as a command line application, you can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

You can also use Jython to run Python on the Java virtual machine.